# Accessing DataDirectory folder from a different project C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have some files in the App_Data folder at project "B" and i want to use some of these files also from project "A".

From B I can easily do

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory")
```

How can I get the "B" DataDirectory path from project "A"?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of projects are they? How does project "A" know that project "B" exists?

Comment: I'd assume a web server project ASP/MVC etc since there is an `App_Data` folder

Comment: They are both web applications (independent sites) in c# .net. For now i've done a handler that retrieves the path from one site to the other one and it seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

As per my Knowledge could you try  this below code:

```
string ExistingFileName = (Server.MapPath(string.Format("/BProject/App_Data/" + Filename));
```